# MoSKito Control: unable to open web app

Tags: monitor

I downloaded the lastest version of MoSKito control war and deployed it into tomcat. I also followed tutorial in this link https://moskito.org/display/MSK/MoSKito-Control+Quick+Setup+Guide and change the configuration in moskitocontrol.json.
However, when I opened the webpage, I always got this error: HTTP Status 404.
So how could I get the tutorial to successfully open MoSKito control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean by "opening the webpage"? What URL are you using?

Default is http://host:port/moskito-control/control/main.

For example http://localhost:8080/moskito-control/control/main.

Regards

Leon